# ffmpeg moving text but only within Y limits

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add text to a video that will scroll from bottom to top; I managed to do it with something similar to this:

`ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=green:x=(w-text_w)/2+20:y=if(lt(t\,2)\,480\,(h-400-(40*t))):textfile=scroll.txt:bordercolor=white:borderw=1" -c:v libx264 -y -preset ultrafast scrolling.mp4`

The original video is 960x540, so the text starts at position y=480 and, after 2 seconds, starts moving up.
That bit works fine, and the text "vanishes" at the top of the frame as it scrolls up.
What I need to achieve is for the text to scroll only within certain Y limits, imagine a virtual box around the text, so it scrolls up only from a certain Y position in the bottom (but not the very bottom) and disappears into a line on the top that isn't the top part of the frame.
Can that be achieved with ffmpeg?

EDIT: Maybe the trick here should be to put the text on top of a transparent video that's smaller in height, and then within the same command somehow merge this new video that has the text with the original video. Not sure how achieve that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, amending duration and positioning as appropriate.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "color=c=white@0.0:s=320x320:duration=30,drawtext=textfile=Credits.txt: x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-t*50:fontcolor=white:fontsize=38:alpha=0.9[textbox];[0][textbox]overlay=eval=init:x=300:y=100[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -i -
```

Where we create a transparent (white@0.0) `color` source, write the text on to it (the `alpha` setting is for text transparency), then `overlay` that on the video.

The text in this example in a file called Credits.txt

```
Start
.
.
.
.
.
Box text
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

...........................
.
.
End
```

[image]

Here you see the word `Start` disappearing, whilst `Line 3` emerges.